# ORA-00904: "\d+$": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

While executing the below query in PL/SQL, I am getting ORA-00904: "\d+$": invalid identifier error.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE " select regexp_substr(table_name, "\d+$") result from user_tables where regexp_like(table_name, "\d+$") " into splitstring;
```

I tried using single quotes also, but still I am facing the same error.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' select regexp_substr(table_name, "\d+$") result from user_tables where regexp_like(table_name, "\d+$") ' into splitstring;
```

Can anyone please help me with this issue

Comment: try the first example but use single quotes around the regex pattern

Comment: I tried but still I am facing same issue

Comment: By default, regular expressions must be enclosed in single quotes. Found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/B14251_01/adfns_regexp.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes are used for string literals; double quotes are used for identifiers.

Start with a static SQL statement that works:

```
select regexp_substr(table_name, '\d+$') result
from user_tables
where regexp_like(table_name, '\d+$')
```

Then to make it dynamic you have to make the whole statement a string; you can either escape the existing quotes by doubling them up - note that is two single-quote characters, not one double-quote character:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select regexp_substr(table_name, ''\d+$'') result
  from user_tables
  where regexp_like(table_name, ''\d+$'')'
into splitstring;
```

or use [the alternative quoting mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA):

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'^select regexp_substr(table_name, '\d+$') result
  from user_tables
  where regexp_like(table_name, '\d+$')^'
into splitstring;
```

You don't need dynamic SQL here though, you can just do:

```
select regexp_substr(table_name, '\d+$') result
into splitstring
from user_tables
where regexp_like(table_name, '\d+$');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=04933a1b4a0c32e6d6139c43403dbcec) - with a single matching table; if there are none, or more than one, then your query into a scalar variable will fail. Depending on what you're doing with the numeric part of the table name(s), you might want to use a cursor and loop over all the extracted values. That's a separate issue though.